# xPath: fetch element with an attribute containing the text of another element

Tags: xpath

Given I have the following HTML structure:

```
<button aria-labelledby="ref-1" id="foo" onclick="convey(event)">action 2</button>
<div class="anotherElement">foobar</div>
<div id="ref-1" hidden>target 2</div>
```

I would like to fetch button by its aria-labelledby attribute. I tried the following options:

```
//*[@aria-labelledby=string(/div[@id="ref-1"]/@id)]
//*[@aria-labelledby = string(.//*[normalize-space() = "target 2"]/@id)]
//*[@aria-labelledby = .//*[normalize-space() = "target 2"]/@id]
```

But wasn't able to fetch the element. Anyone has an idea what the right xPath could be?

Edit: simply put: how do I fetch the button element if my only information is "target 2", and if both elements can be randomly located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//button[@aria-labelledby='ref-1']
```

or

```
//button[@aria-labelledby=(//*/@id)]
```

or

```
//button[@aria-labelledby=(//*[contains(.,'target 2')]/@id)]
```

or

```
//button[@aria-labelledby=(//*[contains(text(),'target 2')]/@id)]
```

?

Comment: Bravo! Thank you so much! So at the end the `(` and `)` did the trick

Comment: @ChristianB not sure exactly what you're after but i added 2 more attempts, re-read it ^^

Answer (score 0):

Since `button` and `div` are the same level siblings here you can use `preceding-sibling` XPath expression like this:

```
//div[text()='target 2']//preceding-sibling::button
```

pay attention with with your actual XML this will match 2 `button` elements.
To make more precise math I think we will need to be based on more details, not only the `target 2` text

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough: the only information I have to fetch the button is "target 2" which is why I have to find it by getting the text of another element

Comment: Ah, OK. How about the updated answer?

Comment: both doesn't work, check http://xpather.com/5bcLhHii , note that buttons text is "action 2"

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time looking into this. Unfortunately it is not guaranteed that these elements are connected, they could be located at arbitrary locations

Comment: Well, this makes the mission impossible. You can not locate element just by "well, we have somewhere element with 'some_text' text" since this will match all the elements in that XML...

Comment: Well one would assume if you can do this `//*[@aria-labelledby="ref-1"]` but you don't have "ref-1" that you can fetch that information by using another attribute query `string(/div[@id="ref-1"]/@id)` - is that not possible?

Comment: @Prophet actually it might be possible given XPath's support for sub-queries, check my answer ^^ but we both have to guess what Christian want to match